# Find value of inputbox in specific row, sheet

Tags: vba

I am very new to VBA and programming. I am attempting the following:

- Click command button btnUpdateEntry to launch an inputbox
- Search for value of inputbox in the sheet "output" in column A
- Go to first location where value found
- Display message if value not found

  ```
  Private Sub btnUpdateEntry_Click()

      Dim StringToFind As String

      StringToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter string to find", "Find string")

      Worksheets("output").Activate
      ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select

          Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="StringToFind", After:=ActiveCell, _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If cell Is Nothing Then
          Worksheets("input").Activate
          MsgBox "String not found"
      End If

  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the double quotes in your `Find` statement:

```
    Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=StringToFind, After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Enclosing this in quotes means to interpret it as a literal string, rather than the variable value held in your variable, `StringToFind`.

There may be other errors. i did not test your code any further. If you need to physically go to the cell, you could use

`Application.GoTo cell`

Or you could use

`cell.Activate`

Answer (score 1):

If the only goal is to activate that cell and view it, all you have to do is:

```
    Selection.Find(what:="yourvalue").Activate
```

So instead of setting cell = the value of the selection, use that above line